# One-liner to identify duplicates using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

In preps for data analyst interview questions, I came across "find all duplicate emails (not unique emails) in "one-liner" using pandas."

The best I've got is not a single line but rather three:

```py
# initialize dataframe 
import pandas as pd
d = {'email':['a','b','c','a','b']}
df= pd.DataFrame(d)

# select emails having duplicate entries
results = pd.DataFrame(df.value_counts())
results.columns = ['count']
results[results['count'] > 1]

>>>
    count
email   
b   2
a   2
```

Could the second block following the latter comment be condensed into a one-liner, avoiding the temporary variable `results`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `duplicated`:

```
>>> df[df.duplicated()]
  email
3     a
4     b
```

Or if you want a list:

```
>>> df[df["email"].duplicated()]["email"].tolist()
['a', 'b']
```